# Python - I'm declaring two arguments, but 1 is missing?

Tags: python, desktop-application, procedural-programming

I'm trying to develop a text editor that replaces user-defined shortcuts with words. I've been able to solve the replace function and tweak it to my design, but I'm having trouble taking the syntax of the console (see code below) and feeding the information to the parent window. However, I keep running into this error and I've been working for a couple days on how to fix this. It keeps saying "replace_shortcut() missing 1 required positional argument: 'shortcut'", but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do. I've looked on other questions on SO, but nothing that's relevant to my problem. (If it helps I'm new to Python, switched over from C/C++)

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

# For the window
root = Tk()
root.title("Scrypt")

# For the parent text
text = Text(root)
text.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

# For console window and text
win1 = Toplevel()
console_text = Text(win1, width=25, height=25)
console_text.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

# For menubar
menubar = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)

def get_console_text(*args):
    syntax = console_text.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
    tokens = syntax.split(" ")
    word = tokens[:1]
    shortcut = tokens[2:3]
    # return word, shortcut

def replace_shortcut(word, shortcut):
    idx = '1.0'
    while 1:
        idx = text.search(shortcut, idx, stopindex=END)
        if not idx: break

        lastidx = '% s+% dc' % (idx, len(shortcut))

        text.delete(idx, lastidx)
        text.insert(idx, word)

        lastidx = '% s+% dc' % (idx, len(word))
        idx = lastidx

def open_console(*args):
    replace_shortcut(get_console_text())
    win1.mainloop()

# Function calls and key bindings
text.bind("<space>", replace_shortcut) and text.bind("<Return>", replace_shortcut)
win1.bind("<Return>", open_console)

# Menu bar
menubar.add_command(label="Shortcuts", command=open_console)

root.mainloop()
```

The traceback (I think that's what it's called):

```
replace_shortcut() missing 1 required positional argument: 'shortcut'
Stack trace:
 >  File "C:\Users\Keaton Lee\source\repos\PyTutorial\PyTutorial\PyTutorial.py", line 42, in open_console
 >    replace_shortcut(get_console_text())
 >  File "C:\Users\Keaton Lee\source\repos\PyTutorial\PyTutorial\PyTutorial.py", line 54, in <module>
 >    root.mainloop()
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing a second declaration that needs to be, well, declared, but any help you guys can offer is appreciated!

Comment: As it says, it requires one more argument. Positional means that you have to supply it specifically, i.e. `replace_shortcut(some_args, shortcut=your_shortcut_variable)`.

Comment: @kwkt Since shortcut is postional, you don't need the `shortcut=` part - `replace_shortcut(some_args, your_shortcut_variable)` is sufficient.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 it seems I got things mixed up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function `get_console_text()` doesn't actually return anything, so when you call `replace_shortcut(get_console_text())`, you are effectively calling `replace_shortcut(None)`

Notice in your `get_console_text()` function the lines are :

```
def get_console_text(*args):
    syntax = console_text.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
    tokens = syntax.split(" ")
    word = tokens[:1]
    shortcut = tokens[2:3]
    # return word, shortcut   <------ you have commented out the return !!!!
```

You also need to do :

```
replace_shortcut(*get_console_text())
```

Note the `*`, this tells Python that the return value from `get_console_text` needs to be unpacked into two arguments before being set to replace_shortcut as two arguments.

Comment: Even then it won't work as the function will return one tuple, not two variables. You'd need to unpack the arguments into the function call, i.e. `replace_shortcut(*get_console_text())`

Comment: Thanks for showing me, Tony Suffolk 66! I totally forgot that I'd commented out that line. I tried unpacking the arguments from the function as Ted Klein Bergman suggested, but I'm still getting the same error. Should I return the word and shortcut at the end of replace shortcut, or would that make the code a bit bloated?

Comment: @bluthhndr Returning both those values and unpacking should resolve the error. If you're still getting the error, then you haven't implemented it correctly, or you have a similar error somewhere else. Make sure to confirm the line number and make sure you're running the correct file (and that you've saved it with all changes before running it)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is clean as other answer and comment pointed out.
Just one more point:
`get_console_text()` will return one object `None`, so the complaint is "missing 1 required positional argument: 'shortcut'", not two arguments.